# css commands with arguments

Tags: html, css

On a website that I am maintaining, I have many code lines like the following one:

```
<strong>doi</strong>
<a href="http://website/reference/" target="_blank">reference</a>
```

where "website" is an actual website address and "reference" is a number which depends on each entry of this type (while the website address is always the same). In html/ccs; is it possible to create a command, let's call it `doi` such that instead of always writing the two lines above, I would equivalently write

```
<doi>reference</doi>
```

Comment: There are no such things as commands in HTML or CSS.

Comment: I see. There is no way I can simplify the way I write the initial information then. Too bad.

Comment: I guess you could use a PHP function.

Comment: Or XSLT. Or even a JavaScript function, as long as you are sure that the user always has JavaScript enabled.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to have an a tag that creates a default url? Or do you want your links to be bolded (like the strong tag). I think what you're probably looking for is a web component type thing.

Comment: @Gina I am trying to replace fairly long html code lines by more compact "commands" replacing, or playing the role of, these long code lines.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible using just html/css, but it is possible using javascript/jquery or a javascript framework, like angularjs.

Here's an example using jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/31dzyjgL/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<doi>121</doi>

<!-- JavaScript -->
$("doi").each(function(){
    var ref = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith( "<strong>doi</strong><a href='http://website/"+ref+"/' target='_blank'>reference</a>" );
});
```

So the script will look for all of your custom "doi" tags, and replace them with the fleshed out label+link with the dynamic reference.